# Pattern Matching in C# 7.0

Tags: switch-statement, pattern-matching, c#-7.0

I found this code snippet in Microsoft's Blog 'New Features in C# 7.0' about Switch-Case Pattern matching:

```
switch(shape)
{
    case Circle c:
        WriteLine($"circle with radius {c.Radius}");
        break;
    case Rectangle s when (s.Length == s.Height):
        WriteLine($"{s.Length} x {s.Height} square");
        break;
    case Rectangle r:
        WriteLine($"{r.Length} x {r.Height} rectangle");
        break;
    default:
        WriteLine("<unknown shape>");
        break;
    case null:
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(shape));
}
```

Now my question:

How can I use it with switch-case or other structures? What is `shape`? Should it be an instance of Shape (a super class of Circle, Rectangle, etc)?

And my second question according to this: How can I use the `when`? Is it a new keyword? In which way do the compiler validate it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#pattern-matching) is the current documentation for **Pattern Matching**.

Yes, `Shape` is a super class of `Circle` and `Rectangle`.

The `when` keyword is used to add extra conditions to the `case` block. Pretty much the way it is used with exception filters (introduced with C# 6).

Comment: Why is this beneficial than say, defining an abstract method in `Shape` and calling it here?

Comment: @Alan, what if you can't?

Comment: Gotcha. That makes sense.